# Ionic- No css working on ios simulator

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a basic app on ionic for ios. I installed ionic framework everything went fine except when I am writing a simple tag with inline css it renders the H1 in default color `<h1 style="color:red">Just display the damn heading in red</h1>`. No other ionic classes are working either, like button, button-calm etc

In not short not a single CSS is applying . I dont know how even this is possible.

Comment: Can you just double check ionic css is included in index.html file

Comment: @PareshGami Not even inline css is working leave aside ionic.css

Comment: can you check simulator console using safari.

Comment: I am running an app for the first time on ios... plz tell me where to find simulator console

Comment: Safari > develop > simulator > here you can see you application name > click on that and click on console tab